# Evaluating a polynomial

Tags: c, mathematics

> You are given a polynomial of degree n. The polynomial is of the form
>
> > P(x) = a<sub>n</sub> · x<sup>n</sup> + a<sub>n-1</sub> · x<sup>n-1</sup> + … + a<sub>0</sub>
>
> where the *a<sub>i</sub>*‘s are the coefficients. Given an integer
>   *x*, write a program that will evaluate *P(x)*.
>
> You are provided with a function named `power( )` that takes two
>   positive integers *x* and *y* and returns *x<sup>y</sup>*. If *y* is
>   0, the function returns 1.
>
> The prototype of this function is
>
> ```
> int power(int x, int y);
> ```
>
> **INPUT:**
>
> - Line 1 contains the integers *n* and *x* separated by whitespace.
> - Line 2 contains the coefficients *a<sub>n</sub>*, *a<sub>n-1</sub>*, …, *a<sub>0</sub>* separated by whitespace.
>
> **OUTPUT:**
>
> A single integer which is *P(x)*.
>
> **CONSTRAINTS:**
>
> The inputs will satisfy the following properties. It is not necessary
>   to validate the inputs.
>
> ```
> 1 <= n <= 10
> 1 <= x <= 10
> 0 <= ai <=10
> ```

My code

```
#include<stdio.h>

int power(int x, int y);

int main()
{

int n,x,a[11],i; unsigned long long int sum=1;
scanf("%d%d",&n,&x);
if(n<1 || n>10) return 0;
if(x<1 || x>10) return 0;



for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
{
scanf("%d",&a[i]);
if(a[i]< 0 || a[i]>10) return 0;
}
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{

sum+=power(x,n-i)*a[i];
}
printf("%llu",sum);

    return 0;
}



int power(int x, int y)
 {
   int result = x,i;

   if(y == 0) return 1;
   if(x < 0 || y < 0) return 0;

   for(i = 1; i < y; ++i)
   result *= x;

   return result;
}
```

Comment: Do you know about [Horner's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method)?

Answer (score 4):

1. Recommend a uniform and more indented style.  E.g.

   ```
   for(i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
       sum+=power(x,n-i)*a[i];
   }
   ```
2. Both `a[11]` and `if(... n>10)` rely on the same value.  Also to avoid undocumented magic numbers, consider the following (also the same for `x` and `a[]`):

   ```
   #define n_MAX (10)
   #define n_MIN (0)
   int a[n_MAX + 1];
   if(n<n_MIN || n>n_MAX) return 0;
   ```
3. `unsigned long long int sum` serves little value in protecting against numbers larger than `INT_MAX` as `power()` is the most likely candidate to overflow.  (Strictly speaking, it is not even known that `LLONG_MAX` is greater than `INT_MAX`.)  So if you want a larger range, re-write `power()` as `unsigned long long power(int x, int y)`, otherwise leaving `sum` as `int` is OK.

   Else suggest for marginal range improvement:

   ```
   sum += (unsigned long long) power(x,n-i) * a[i];
   ```
4. BTW: should not it be:

   ```
   unsigned long long int sum = 0;  //( 0 not 1)
   ```
5. Note: Stated objective says "It is not necessary to validate the inputs.".  Still I like the testing you have done.  Possible that the final reviewer (teacher?) may object to unneeded code.  *Could* wrap in an `#if DEBUG` macro...
6. [Faster way to do `power()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101439/the-most-efficient-way-to-implement-an-integer-based-power-function-powint-int)
7. See no reason for `x<0` test in `if(x < 0 || y < 0) return 0;`.  Could be

   ```
   if (y < 0) return 0;
   ```
8. Do `power()` with `unsigned` rather than `int` as " function named power( ) that takes two positive integers x and y".
9. @Constructor comment leads to an excellent suggestion.  Calculate `sum` with a loop that does the below.  No need for a power function.  Running `sum` can be `unsigned long long` and code gets great range.  Its faster & simple.

   ```
   // sum = (((a[n]*x + a[n-1])*x + a[n-2])*x + .... )*x + a[0];

   // Something like
   unsigned long long sum = 0;
   for (int i=n; i>=0; i--) {
     sum *= x;
     sum += a[i];
   }
   ```
10. Lastly, even the array `a` is not needed:

    ```
    #include<stdio.h>
    int main() {
      int n;
      unsigned x, a;
      unsigned long long sum = 0;
      scanf("%d%u", &n, &x);
      while (n-- >= 0) {
        scanf("%u", &a);
        sum *= x;
        sum += a;
      }
      printf("%llu", sum);
      return 0;
    }
    ```

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this problem without using a power function. However, you can optimize your POW(x,y) to O(logn) using Divide and conquer approach,

> ```
>  A^n = A^(n/2) * A^(n/2) if n is even
>      = A^(n/2) * A^(n/2) * A if n is odd
> ```

```
int power(int x, unsigned int y)
{
    int temp;
    if( y == 0)
        return 1;
    temp = power(x, y/2);
    if (y%2 == 0)
        return temp*temp;
    else
        return x*temp*temp;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A few suggestions:

- Whitespace (formatting) makes the code more readable: be especially careful with indentation; and don't waste vertical space with too many empty lines because you want to see the whole function on your limited-size screen)
- Don't declare variables before you assign a value to them. Declaring all your variables at the top of the function was necessary in old-style C but is [no longer required](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2321622/49942).
- You don't need the `a[11]` array.
- You don't need to write the `power` function because the specifications say, "**You are provided with** a function ..."
- You don't need to validate your input (normally you should; but the specifications which you quoted for this problem say that you needn't: and you should usually read and obey the specifications).
- The biggest possible value of x<sup>n</sup> is 10<sup>10</sup> for which you'll need a more-than-32-bit integer:

  - Is this is a trick question, or an mistake by whoever wrote the specs?
  - Is the `power` function (which returns `int`) implicitly working with 64-bit integers?
  - Do you need to define your own version of the `power` function using `int64_t`?
- If you want to declare an explicitly-64-bit integer it's called [`int64_t`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6013417/49942).

If your compiler doesn't support 64-bit arithmetic you can implement it yourself but that makes the code a bit more complicated.

The following is FYI my attempt to do this problem in minimum/cleanest lines of code:

```
int main()
{
    // Line 1 contains the integers n and x separated by whitespace.
    int n, x;
    scanf("%d%d", &n, &x);

    int64_t sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; ++i) {
        // Line 2 contains the coefficients an, an-1, ..., a0 separated by whitespace.
        int a;
        scanf("%d", &a);
        sum += a * power(x, n - i);
    }

    // Use PRId64 defined in <inttypes.h> to print int64_t
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/9225648/49942
    printf("%" PRId64, sum);
    return 0;
}
```

You may agree that my version is more readable than yours; partly because it's shorter.

I added comments which [describe the problem being solved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/400436/49942) (by copying them from the specification).